# HTML5 - Send message button not returning my function?

Tags: python, html

I'm brand new to coding and am following the Udemy Zero to Mastery course.  I'm currently having trouble getting my HTML5 to process a function I've made in Python.  I want to return my function, submit_form, when I click on 'send message'.  Here's the HTML5:

```
<section id="three">
            <h2>Get In Touch</h2>
            <p>This is the contact section.</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-8 col-12-small">
                    <form method="post" action="index.html">
                        <div class="row gtr-uniform gtr-50">
                            <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall"><input type="text" name="name" id="name"
                                    placeholder="Name" /></div>
                            <div class="col-6 col-12-xsmall"><input type="email" name="email" id="email"
                                    placeholder="Email" /></div>
                            <div class="col-12"><textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message"
                                    rows="4"></textarea></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <ul class="actions">
                        <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Send Message</button> -->
                        <li><input type="button" value="Send Message" /></li>
                        </form>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

And here is my python function:

```
@app.route('/submit_form', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submit_form():
    return 'form submitted!'
```

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding how to make the send message button return my function.  Any help is much appreciated, thank you!